# Need to hide particular hidden metadata values

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to hide the hidden type metadata information from the console and network tab (F12). I'm having the metadata information, in that lot of types are there, but for the **hidden**  type selection, If I select the hidden type by using below the console

```
<option id="ember11079" class="ember-view select-option" value="hidden">
<script id="metamorph-1890-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
hidden
<script id="metamorph-1890-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></option>
```

I'm getting the below information from the network tab(F12),

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZHAeGq1ANBBRpGJM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

hidden
------WebKitFormBoundaryZHAeGq1ANBBRpGJM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="label"

some
------WebKitFormBoundaryZHAeGq1ANBBRpGJM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"


------WebKitFormBoundaryZHAeGq1ANBBRpGJM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="icon"

$blank
------WebKitFormBoundaryZHAeGq1ANBBRpGJM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Type"

hidden

------WebKitFormBoundaryZHAeGq1ANBBRpGJM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rc"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryZHAeGq1ANBBRpGJM--
```

Actually, If that type is hidden means the whole metadata filled information needs to disable or hide from the Inspect tab(F12) of network and console too.

javascript I'm using like below:

```
if (data instanceof Array) {
                $(data).each(function () {
                    $("<input type='hidden'>").attr({
                        name : this.name,
                        value : this.value
                    }).appendTo(form);
                });
            } else {
                $.each(data || {}, function (name, value) {
                    $("<input type='hidden'>").attr({
                        name : name,
                        value : value
                    }).appendTo(form);
                });
            }
```

Comment: you can't - once you've sent the html page to a browser, the browser must be able to "see" it

Answer (score 0):

If you on PHP, maybe you need [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)...